# Mysql crashing few times a day

Tags: mysql, linux, sockets

I'm seeing the same thing on CentOS 6.5, which I did not see on 6.4 or prior. This is with MySQL 5.1.71.
Upon CentOS shutdown, the socket file from the running mysqld is not cleaned up and remains on reboot.

In my */etc/my.cnf I have:*

*socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock*

Even though ps shows no mysqld running, the file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists.
My work-around is to remove that file as root, then I'm able to start mysql with

*service mysqld start*

However, the mysql.sock file doesn't get cleaned up properly with

*service mysqld stop*

So it must have to do with the CentOS 6.5 shutdown or MySQL's response to it.

Just now I had another crash. Here's last logs

```
140124 20:28:07 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:17 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:28:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:57:49 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 20:58:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:56 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:01:57 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Got an error writing communication packets
140124 21:33:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140124 21:33:42  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
140124 21:33:42  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140124 21:33:42  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140124 21:33:43  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 16909546
140124 21:33:43 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140124 21:33:43 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.71'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

So as I wrote before if I remove mysql.sock I can start mysql again, but this is temporary solution, because after some time it crashes again. Any suggestion how to fix it once and for all?

Answer (score 0):

seems like  a networking error . you can try few things.
one is to add the following to your my.cnf (trial and error)

```
net_write_timeout=120 
max_allowed_packet
```

and other options is if you execute large number of queries (one after the other) put a sleep between two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `FIFO`s use TCP/IP?

Comment: Let's say Im total newbie in all this stuff. So can you explain your answer?

Comment: Unix pipes get blocked. TCP/IP would be better. You would have nothing having anything hanging around on the OS.